# How do I represent 1 + "" in conditional formatting?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a formula that spits out 1 and "" in the same cell. (its an &) anyway it stopped the conditional formatting from recognizing the cell's value as 1. What value can I use to make the formatting work again?

Comment: That should work, what formula are you using for conditional? What formulae creates the "" or 1?

Comment: I was using =IF($A$1="a",IF(1>$Z$14,grey,IF(AC$2>4,1,0)))&IF($A$1="b",IF(1>$Z$15,grey,IF(AC$12>4,1,0)),"") the first part creates the 1, used to make the cell completely white, while the second in the case of a would give ""                      The grey is being used to make the cell the same colour as the background with conditional formatting

Comment: Where are you using that formula? Is `grey` a range name or did you just forget to put quotes around it? Do you expect anything to turn grey because of that formula?

Comment: Instead of `1`, you should use `"1"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you concatenate a number with a string, even if the string is empty, the result will be a string, not a number.

So change the formula that "spits out" 1 and "" in the same cell to something that retains the number data type.

Explain what you want to achieve with the formula. You combine two IF Statements and both return numbers for the TRUE part. You concatenate the numbers to text. What do you expect to happen if both IF evaluate to TRUE?

Comment: What i was doing with the formula was taking data from a table and forcing cells into stacks based on numbers from 1 to 5, where 5 was a stack of 5 black cells. due to what happens in the sheet, the statements cannot be true at the same time. Edit: Re read your answer and having the conditional formatting if the value is ="1" worked, thank you